# How to view and analyse content of the oracle trace file

Tags: oracle11g

I used oracle 11g2 on a windows 7.
Oracle Provide alert log file and trace file. 
Something Happen wrong in system then both file comes into picture. 
But Alert file can easy to understand and decode some information when Trace file is hard to understand a what correctly happen in system and what wrong.

Any one can give a hint our some tools how to extract some information like Process or some error ora -0600 with some arguments ,ora 7445, instance termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use license version database then  go to oracle support and find relevant document.

You can also attach file of trace and alert  in Oracle Support.